# How to use .htaccess to remove '?m=1' in the end of url?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I just moved my blog from Blogger to WordPress, and have a problem with the mobile URL.

WordpPress have a function to setup URL structure, so the URL for desktop is OK, but there is an additional `?m=1` in mobile version Blogger URL.

This is what I'm trying to do:

redirect `http://www.example.com/2016/05/artical.html?m=1`
to `http://www.example.com/2016/05/artical.html`

I tried this but it didn't work:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)(^|&)m=1(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1?%1%3 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: That looks fairly reasonable, although it might cause you to end up with `asdf?&var2=2`. You are testing with permanent redirects though, so a previous try might be cached. Futhermore, as you are using wordpress this is not the only rule in your .htaccess. Please include the entire .htaccess file for better answers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hope this helps just after `RewriteEngine On`

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^m=1$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1? [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Yes it works perfectly! Thank you very much! I've been trying to solve this for whole day!!

Comment: You are welcome, Please accept answer, so it will help others as well